# Is there a way I can count a specific string (Product) in a column times by the neighboring cell (Quantity) so show how much of a product I have sold

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to count the amount of "Product" I have sold for a specific Item time the quantity I have sold
Example:
One transaction I sold 1x (QTY Column) "Product 1" (Product Column) and in another transaction I have sold 3x (QTY Column) "Product 1" (Product Column). A different cell shows that I have sold 4x "Product 1"

[Image of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQF1M.png)

I have tried counting the amount of times a specific string has been put down times the quantity in the right column for each cell that is being counted but had no luck creating that formula.

Help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!
This has flown over my head.

Comment: You should probably try using a pivot table rather than a formula.

Comment: What you are describing is the exact case for SUMIF().  In your example you will use `=SUMIF(C2:C500,”Product 1”,D2:D500)`.  This says “sum the values in column D only for those rows where column C = ‘Product 1’”.